Shadcn UI creates components in the root instead of resources/js with Vite and Laravel
I'm using Shadcn UI in a project that uses Vite and Laravel. However, I'm facing an issue: when I init Shadcn using npx shadcn@latest init, folders components and libs generated at the root of my project instead of being placed in the resources/js/components folder, which is where I would like it to be.
My vite.config.ts configuration:
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import path from "node:path";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.tsx"],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js"),
        },
    },
});

Desired directory structure:
project-root
├── resources
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── app.tsx
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   ├── MyComponent.tsx
│   │   │   └── AnotherComponent.tsx
│   │   └── ...
├── vite.config.ts
└── ...

Issue:
When I run the shadcn-ui init command or create a new component, it is placed in the root of the project, creating a components folder next to vite.config.ts instead of being created inside resources/js/components.
What I've tried:

Adjusting the alias in vite.config.ts to ensure that @ points to resources/js.
Manually moving the components to the resources/js/components folder and adjusting the imports in my code.
Searched for a setting in Shadcn UI that would allow me to define the components' path, but I couldn't find any.

Question:
How can I configure Shadcn UI or adjust the process so that components are created directly in resources/js/components instead of at the root of the project? Is there any way to set a default output path for the components generated by Shadcn UI?

the same but in remix, initially it installed in app/ folder, but after some time it started to installing to root directory

After run npx shadcn-ui@0.8.0 init and npx shadcn-ui@0.8.0 add button the folder components/ui was created inside resources/js folder. It's probably a bug or missing configuration in the new shadcn package

@ViniciusGomes thanks. I have tried from the latest version to 1.0.0, it turns out that what I need is in 0.8. This bug is very annoying.

You'll have a components.json file in your root directory. In that file, you need to define the aliases. These aliases path will be used by shadcn to place the components in the defined folder.
Eg:
"aliases": {
    "components": "resources/js/components", // assuming resources folder is at the project root
    "utils": "resources/js/lib/utils"
 }

Ref - https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/4014#issuecomment-2174497315

I tried this, but when I run npx shadcn@latest add button the componets/ui folder is created in the root of the project and not in resources/js/components/ui.
